# Can I get the Chicago Lightning Uniform offline?

Tags: la-noire

Does anyone know if you can get the Chicago lightning outfit offline in L.A. Noir?

Answer (score 2):

### No.

The Chicago Lightning outfit can only be unlocked by connecting to Rockstar Social Club.

Comment: Well, that's the thing, I do not have xbox live and I really like it. I play on  xbox 360. Isn't there a cheat code or something

Comment: @Nathaniel No, unfortunately there are no cheats in LA Noire. Even if there were they probably wouldn't let you unlock the suit, the reason it's not in the game by default is because they want you to connect to their service.